# Laravel/PHP: Using whereIn to make a query for specific field of object

Tags: php, laravel

I have a query that gives me an array of Product objects

```
$products = Product::where('id', != $excludedId)->get();

// [ {id: 43, name: "Sunglasses", price: 4432}, {id: 44, name: "Shirt", price: 4212} ]
```

I want to make a query that checks `SaleItems` and gets all the SaleItems that have a `sale_id` that is an `id` with the array above, so any SaleItem with a `sale_id` of [43,44] would be valid.

```
 $saleItems = SaleItems::whereIn('sale_id', ???)
```

I am just not sure what to query against.  Do I need to make a separate array of just the product_ids or can I use my existing $products variable somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can directly get product_ids using [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck):

```
$product_ids=Product::where('id', '!=', $excludedId)->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

or if you want $products collection for some reason you can get ids from it:

```
$products = Product::where('id', != $excludedId)->get();
$product_ids=$products->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

then:

```
 $saleItems = SaleItems::whereIn('sale_id', $product_ids);
```